# Dua between adhaan and iqama

Tags: dua

One of the best times to ask dua is between adhaan and iqama. Since iqama is addressed to those already in the mosque rather than a reminder for those outside, if a person who is at home uses this time for dua will it be considere a "best time" for that individual.

Comment: Check out this! [This is might help](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17768/when-you-make-dua-when-do-you-stop-if-what-you-asking-for-doesnt-seem-to-come/23052#23052)

Comment: its obviously about the place, where jamat is getting ready for salah (masjid) not in home..

Answer (score 2):

Salaams
look we cant say it's not accepted, as Allah SWT is the one who accepts and rejects our duah, but everything does come down to our intention. The best thing to do is to probably go to the mosque as much as possible, but even if you cant, noone can say it's not accepted, and noone can say it is
May Allah SWT accept all our duahs and place us in the highest level of jannah, Amen

Comment: Well said, @tashanna